# How can I get the Correct Current Time in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, time, nstimezone

I know this it the repeated question. I have reviewed many answers but still didn’t get any solution.

My question is,
How can I get the Time of Device if user have set it manually..?

I have implemented one chatting app. But in this app, I have issues of timings. If user have set manually time then how can we identify that.?

I want to get correct current UTC time. So using this, I can identify the difference between device time and UTC time.

If we are using, `NSDate *currentDateAndTime = [NSDate date];`, then it returns only UTC time according to device, not the current UTC time.

Is there any easy way to find out this solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a web service if you don't trust the device's time.

Comment: ... or a NTP server, see e.g. this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964318/how-can-i-get-the-actual-date-and-time-if-the-device-date-and-time-are-inaccurat.

Answer (score 17):

There is no trusted time source in iOS. You just operate with monotonic and non-monotonic time.

**Monotonic** time (or absolute time) represents the absolute elapsed wall-clock time since some arbitrary, fixed point in the past. The `CACurrentMediaTime()` or `mach_absolute_time` return monotonic time.

**Non-monotonic** time represents the machine's best-guess as to the current wall-clock, time-of-day time. It can jump forwards and backwards as the system time-of-day clock is changed. The `[NSDate date]` call returns it.

As an option, you can take the trusted date/time from the http `Date` response header. Then save it and current monotonic time(`CACurrentMediaTime()`) in the keychain.
Here is the way to get the current trusted time:

`last known online time + (CACurrentMediaTime() - saved monotonic time)`

Another solution would be to use NTP server.

Answer (score 2):

This might solve your problem

```
NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
        NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
        NSLog(@"current time is:%@",currentTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code it helps you

```
NSDate * datee = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];

NSLog(@"%@",localDateString);
```

Comment: I want to get correct current time. It will returns current time of device, not the current UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

Use : `NSDate *currentDateAndTime = [NSDate date];`

This will get you the absolute date and time in GMT reference zone.

Comment: It is not working, if you are setting manually time without using any time zone. It will returns on device time with UTC time.

Comment: Device always works using UTC time. Only the display of time use timeZone precision, but for display only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

swift:

```
let date = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")

dateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone

println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))
```

Obj-C:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];

[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];       
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for getting current time:-

## Swift 3

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00") //Current time zone
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:MM a"
let currentTime: String = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
print("My Current Time is \(currentTime)")

Result **
Output : - "My Current Time is 11:05 AM\n"
```